# How do I find something in Google cache?

Tags: google-search

Here's a scenario. Someone I don't fully trust posts on a forum that he saw some interesting materials in some specific Twitter account tweets and cites those materials.

I want to ***be sure that material has been indeed posted there***. I go to the tweets and don't see those materials - either they've been deleted or they haven't been published there in the first place.

The "one size fits all" solution is to use Google cache, isn't? How do I do that? I query

> PhraseFromThatMaterial cache:twitter.com/AccountName

and see empty resultset. What does it mean? How do I use Google Search cache in this scenario?

Comment: what's done is done.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try a different approach:

Go to Google and search for 'twitter accountname' - select the 'cache' link for the account in question. You will then have access the cache version of their twitter front page.

Chances are that you will be disappointed, because unless the posts you are after happen to be on the first page of that snapshot, you won't be able to retrieve them.

Another long-shot would be to try the [Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php)... but I don't fancy your chances.