# Trying to pull data from website into Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, importhtml

I'm trying to pull the data from this website into a Google Sheet

https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.194.html

I've used =importhtml or =importxml in the past for this site, but I can't get it to work now. Could something have changed on their website that won't allow the table to be pulled? The command I've used in the past was

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.194.html","table",2)
```

But that no longer works for me. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the formula is working now.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when i tried the formula you shared - but additionally this also works:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.194.html","//tr")`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard or even impossible to know for people that are not following the referred page if something changed to it. You could take a look to the cache on Google or to the Wayback Machine from https://archive.org to find that.

Regarding IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML they only are able to access the content in the source code of the page; they can't access code added by using client-side JavaScript

Related Q&A

- [How do I find something in Google cache?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13820/88163)
- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)